# Catch the following capture groups with a regex and then reorder them with re sub method if the pattern is detected

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

```
import re

input_text = "05 del 07 del 2000 del 09 hhggh" #example 0 - Not modify!
input_text = "04 del 05 del 07 del 2000" #example 1 - Not modify!
input_text = "04 05 del 06 de 200" #example 2 - Yes modify!
input_text = "04 05 del 06 de 20076 55" #example 3 - Yes modify!

detection_regex_obligatory_preposition = r"\d{2}" + r"[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de )[\s|]" + r"\d{2}" + r"[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de )[\s|]" + r"\d*"

year, month, days_intervale_or_day = "", "", "" # = group()[2], group()[1], group()[0]
date_restructuring_structure = days_intervale_or_day + "-" + month + "-" + year
print(repr(date_restructuring_structure))

input_text = re.sub(detection_regex_obligatory_preposition, date_restructuring_structure, input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

**Correct outputs** for each of these cases

```
""
"05 del 07 del 2000 del 09 hhggh" #example 0 - Not modify!

""
"04 del 05 del 07 del 2000" #example 1 - Not modify!

"05-06-200"
"04 05-06-200" #example 2 - Yes modify!

"05-06-20076"
"04 05-06-20076 55" #example 3 - Yes modify!
```

In the **example 1** should not be replaced since there is more than one day indicated in front of it, leaving something like this
`\d{2} del \d{2} del \d{2} del \d*` and not this `\d{2} del \d{2} del \d*`

Something similar happens in **example 0** where there is no need to perform the replacement since this `\d{2} del \d{2} del \d* de \d{2}` or `\d{2} del \d{2} del \d* de \d*` and not this `\d{2} del \d{2} del \d*`

How to set the capture groups and the regex to be able to perform the replacements of **examples 2 and 3**, but not those of **examples 0 and 1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/w7Yp7J/1

```py
import re

#input_text = "05 del 07 del 2000 del 09 hhggh" #example 0 - Not modify!
#input_text = "04 del 05 del 07 del 2000" #example 1 - Not modify!
input_text = "04 05 del 06 de 200" #example 2 - Yes modify!
input_text = "04 05 del 06 de 20076 55" #example 3 - Yes modify!

detection_regex_obligatory_preposition = r"(?P<startDay>\d{2})[\s|](?P<finishDay>\d{2})[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de )[\s|](?P<month>\d{2})[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de)[\s|](?P<year>\d*)"

date_restructuring_structure = "\g<startDay> \g<finishDay>-\g<month>-\g<year>"

input_text = re.sub(detection_regex_obligatory_preposition, date_restructuring_structure, input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

---

To see your code on Regex101, I combined your rules as the following:

```
\d{2}[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de )[\s|]\d{2}[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de)[\s|]\d*
```

I realized that it grabs the inputs, which are the exact opposite of what we want. Like the following:

```
05 del 07 del 2000 del 09 hhggh #example 0 - Captured
04 del 05 del 07 del 2000 #example 1 - Captured
04 05 del 06 de 200 #example 2 - Not Captured
04 05 del 06 de 20076 55 #example 3 - Not Captured
```

To grab the correct inputs, I modified your rule by adding two digit number rule (`\d{2}`) to the beginning:

```
\d{2}[\s|]\d{2}[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de )[\s|]\d{2}[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de)[\s|]\d*
```

Now, it grabs the correct inputs, and we can turn our faces to replacement rules. There are two kinds of replacement rules. The first one is the number format (Like: `\1 \2-\3-\4` in our case), which is the default behavior. When you wrap something with parenthesis, it is in number format. The second is name format (Like: `\g<startDay> \g<finishDay>-\g{month}-\g{year}` in our case), which I prefer. To make name-format replacements, you need to use named capturing groups `(?P<startDay>***)`.

Let's add named capturing groups to our rule:

```
(?P<startDay>\d{2})[\s|](?P<finishDay>\d{2})[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de )[\s|](?P<month>\d{2})[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de)[\s|](?P<year>\d*)
```

The final code:

```py
import re

#input_text = "05 del 07 del 2000 del 09 hhggh" #example 0 - Not modify!
#input_text = "04 del 05 del 07 del 2000" #example 1 - Not modify!
input_text = "04 05 del 06 de 200" #example 2 - Yes modify!
input_text = "04 05 del 06 de 20076 55" #example 3 - Yes modify!

detection_regex_obligatory_preposition = r"(?P<startDay>\d{2})[\s|](?P<finishDay>\d{2})[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de )[\s|](?P<month>\d{2})[\s|](?:del|de[\s|]el|de)[\s|](?P<year>\d*)"

date_restructuring_structure = "\g<startDay> \g<finishDay>-\g<month>-\g<year>"

input_text = re.sub(detection_regex_obligatory_preposition, date_restructuring_structure, input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write and shorten the pattern to 4 capture groups:

```
(\d{2})\s(\d{2})\sdel?\s(\d{2})\sdel?\s(\d+)
```

And in the replacement use the groups: `\1 \2-\3-\4`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G9JZeB/1)

---

Or with the named captured groups:

```
(?P<startDay>\d{2})\s(?P<finishDay>\d{2})\sdel?\s(?P<month>\d{2})\sdel?\s(?P<year>\d+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?P<startDay>\d{2})` Match 2 digits in group *startDay*
- `\s` Match a whitespace char
- `(?P<finishDay>\d{2})` Match 2 digits in grou *finishDay*
- `\sdel?\s` Match either `de` or `del` between whitespace chars
- `(?P<month>\d{2})` Match 2 digits in group *month*
- `\sdel?\s` Match either `de` or `del` between whitespace chars
- `(?P<year>\d+)` Match 1+ digits in group *year*

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pMfVPQ/1).